# Loop through rows and variables with same prefix

Tags: r

Suppose we have the following data:

```
d <- data.frame(
  "V" = c("A", "B"),
  "X1" = c("A", "A"),
  "X2" = c("B","B"),
  "X3" = c("C", "C"),
  "Y1" = c(1, 4),
  "Y2" = c(2, 5),
  "Y3" = c(3, 6)
)
d[] <- lapply(d, as.character)

d
  V X1 X2 X3 Y1 Y2 Y3
1 A  A  B  C  1  2  3
2 B  A  B  C  4  5  6
```

I want to create a variable VAL that will take the value of Y[n] if V=X[n]

I can do it with ifelse statements but I want to avoid nested ifelse because n is unknown

```
d$VAL_ifelse = ifelse(d$V == d$X1,d$Y1,
                      ifelse(d$V == d$X2,d$Y2,
                             ifelse(d$V == d$X3,d$Y3,NA)))
```

I tried to create this loop but problem is with j I think ?

```
d_X_var=grep("^X", names(d), value=TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
  for(j in 1:length(d_X_var)){
    if((d[i,c('V')] == d[i,paste0('X',j)]) == TRUE){
      d$VAL_loop[i] <- as.character(d[i,paste0('Y',j)])
    } else if((d[i,c('V')] != d[i,paste0('X',j)]) == TRUE){
      d$VAL_loop[i] <- NA
    }
  }
}

d
  V X1 X2 X3 Y1 Y2 Y3 VAL_ifelse VAL_loop
1 A  A  B  C  1  2  3          1     <NA>
2 B  A  B  C  4  5  6          5     <NA>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `max.col` from `base R`in a vectorized way

```
d$Val <- d[5:7][cbind(seq_len(nrow(d)), max.col(d$V == d[2:4], 'first'))]
d
#   V X1 X2 X3 Y1 Y2 Y3 Val
#1 A  A  B  C  1  2  3   1
#2 B  A  B  C  4  5  6   5
```

#### Update

If there are no matches we can get the output as `NA` with `rowSums` (data from the comments)

```
d <- data.frame( "V" = c("A", "B","C","D","C"), "X1" = c("A", "A","A","A","A"), "X2" = c("B","B","B","B","A"), "X3" = c("C", "C","C","D","A"), "Y1" = c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13), "Y2" = c(2, 5, 8, 11, 14), "Y3" = c(3, 6, 9, 12,15), "Val_expected" = c(1,5,9,12,NA) ) 
d[,] <- lapply(d, as.character) 

d$Val <- d[5:7][cbind(seq_len(nrow(d)), max.col(d$V == d[2:4], 'first'))]
d$Val <- as.numeric(d$Val) * (NA^ !rowSums(d$V == d[2:4]))
d$Val
#[1]  1  5  9 12 NA
```

Comment: Thanks but Val should be NA if V is not in any X variables d <- data.frame(
  "V" = c("A", "B","C","D","C"),
  "X1" = c("A", "A","A","A","A"),
  "X2" = c("B","B","B","B","A"),
  "X3" = c("C", "C","C","D","A"),
  "Y1" = c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13),
  "Y2" = c(2, 5, 8, 11, 14),
  "Y3" = c(3, 6, 9, 12,15),
  "Val_expected" = c(1,5,9,12,NA)
)
d[,] <- lapply(d, as.character)

Answer (score 4):

We can use vectorized way to get `VAL`

```
d$Val <- d[5:7][which(d[2:4] == d$V, arr.ind = TRUE)]

d
#  V X1 X2 X3 Y1 Y2 Y3 Val
#1 A  A  B  C  1  2  3   1
#2 B  A  B  C  4  5  6   5
```

The above is true when you know the column numbers beforehand of `X` and `Y` columns. If you don't know we can use `grep` first to get column numbers and then subset.

```
X_cols <- grep("^X", names(d))
Y_cols <- grep("^Y", names(d))
d$Val <- d[Y_cols][which(d[X_cols] == d$V, arr.ind = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly convoluted way using `ifelse` and `diag`:

```
d$Val <- ifelse(d$V == diag(as.matrix(d[,2:4])), diag(as.matrix(d[,5:7])), NA)
```

**Output:**

```
  V X1 X2 X3 Y1 Y2 Y3 Val
1 A  A  B  C  1  2  3   1
2 B  A  B  C  4  5  6   5
```